# Generating ques-answer pairs from unstructured text

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have to create a system that generates all possible question answer pairs from unstructured text in a specific domain.Many questions may have the same answer but the system should generate all possible types of questions that an answer can have.The questions formed should be meaningful and grammatically correct.
For this purpose, I used nltk and trained an NER, creating entities according to my domain and then I created some rules to identify the question word using the combination of NER identified entities and POS tagged words. But this approach isn't working fine as I am not able to create meaningful questions from the text. Moreover, some question words are wrongly identified and some question words are missed. I also read research papers on using RNN for this purpose but I don't have a large training data since the domain is pretty small. Can anyone suggest a better approach?